# C-i combination doesn't work with lowercase i

Tags: key-bindings, evil, doom

I've configured Doom emacs to run an interactive evil-ex command in visual mode, the reaconfiguration is as below:

```
(defun evil-insert-into-lines ()
  (interactive)
  (evil-ex "'<,'>norm I"))

(defun evil-append-to-lines ()
  (interactive)
  (evil-ex "'<,'>norm A"))

(define-key evil-visual-state-map (kbd "C-i") 'evil-insert-into-lines)
(define-key evil-visual-state-map (kbd "C-a") 'evil-append-to-lines)
```

The second function is invoked both by pressing C-a and C-shift-a (C-A) but the first function only works when I press (C-shift-i). Anyone has any idea what could be the reason?

Comment: `C-i` is the `TAB` character, so there is probably some kind of conflict happening on that basis.  What do `C-h k C-i` and `C-h k C-S-i` report?

Comment: @phils `C-h k C-i` says it's bound to `better jump forward`  but `C-S-i` is bound to my function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Now I get the idea, `C-i` is the same thing as `TAB` character so binding it to a function is a little tricky. [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11319885) anwer worked for me. Here's the new config:

```
(define-key input-decode-map (kbd "C-i") (kbd "H-i"))
(define-key evil-visual-state-map (kbd "H-i") 'evil-insert-into-lines)
```

Answer (score 0):

Spacemacs has a variable to turn on/off translation of <kbd>C-i</kbd> under GUI emacs. Perhaps you could try these lines or look for if doom emacs has similar feature provided.

[Relevant Code](https://github.com/syl20bnr/spacemacs/blob/42dbd1d3597fb11f697fc80902472cbac836fe02/core/core-keybindings.el#L31-L43)